# Image widget not showing the image under the future builder but snapshot have image data

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-provider, flutter-widget

Image widget not showing the image under the future builder but snapshot have image data .Please help me  snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done ?doctor.avatar != null ? Image(image: NetworkImage(snapshot.data.avatar), fit: BoxFit.cover,) :Image.asset(R.image.defaultDoctorImage) : LinearProgressIndicator()

Comment: add more code. And can you share your api link as well

Comment: Please reformat the code you pasted here. It is not showing because you aren't returning a widget. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ek8ZPdWj4Qo to learn about FutureBuilders